# writing unicode string to binary file in perl

Tags: perl, file, unicode, binary

I have a string that contains charactures that are not UTF8, such as "עברית"
I want to write the string to a file without encoding the string. To do so, I opened the file for writing as binary:

```
open my $fh, ">>:raw", "/tmp/bla";
print $fh $mystring;
close $fh;
```

The problem is that the file is corrupted. I open it in a binary view and some bytes are corrupted. 
Am I doing something wrong? Is it not possible writing the string to a file without encoding it?

Comment: How is it not UTF8? If it was opened correctly, it would be in UTF8 internally.

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment is correct, doing so is wrong. [You must encode text](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html#SUMMARY). [`:raw` is for binary data](http://p3rl.org/PerlIO), e.g. images. If you find UTF-8 unsuitable, perhaps you were looking for the encodings ISO-8859-8 or Windows-1255 instead.

Read http://p3rl.org/UNI to learn about the topic of encoding in Perl.

Comment: But why is this incorrect? I dont undertstand. Cant I write the string as binary? I have a problem encoding it, because i dont have any control on the applications that read the file and will have to decode it which are written not in perl but in c.

Comment: @Shay, So what encoding does your C program expect?

Comment: @daxim To save a PDF file, I have found nothing else that works except to write it as binary.  E.g., open(PDF, ">$filename"); binmode PDF; print PDF $contents, writing the file as a binary.  Afterwards I can open it in vim and read it as text, though parts look pretty funny.  Any attempt to write it with an encoding ruins the file.  Why are PDFs an exception?

Comment: That's because a PDF is not text, but binary data. As I wrote in my post, the `:raw` layer is appropriate. `binmode` on a file handle achieves the same in an old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is the representation of text using bytes. For example,

```
ת  === UTF-8 ==========>  D7 AA
ת  === Windows-1255 ===>  FA
ת  === iso-8859-8 =====>  FA
```

It's impossible to store text in a file without encoding it because files can only contain bytes.

Your code works if `$mystring` already contains bytes (encoded text), but you say you have a "Unicode string".

---

I presume you attained the conclusion that your file is corrupted using

```
cat file
```

or similar. In that case, you want the file to be encoded as per your locale.

```
use open ':locale';
open my $fh, ">>", "file" or die $!;
print $fh $mystring;
```